# Ruby Mutex Synchronize without wait

Tags: ruby, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Mutex.html

Is there a way for Mutex.Synchronize to return immediately rather than waiting to obtain the lock, if it is being held by another thread at the time?

In other words, the same behavior as try_lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`synchronize` merely

> Obtains a lock, runs the block, and releases the lock when the block completes.

Here's Rubinius' [implementation](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/2.2/kernel/common/mutex.rb#L59-L66)

```
class Mutex
  def synchronize
    lock
    begin
      yield
    ensure
      unlock
    end
  end
end
```

You can easily adopt this to write your own `try_synchronize`:

```
class Mutex
  def try_synchronize
    return unless try_lock
    begin
      yield
    ensure
      unlock
    end
  end
end
```

MRI throws an exception if no block is given, so you might want to add a:

```
raise ThreadError, 'must be called with a block' unless block_given?
```